# Within char device, where do i put ioread?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I've got a pci device and all I want is to read its memory by "cat"ing from /dev/pcidevice. My first attempt for the char device's read function looked like this:

```
ssize_t cdev_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buffer, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos) {

    ssize_t retval = 0;
    struct mypci_dev *device = filp->private_data;

/* reading data from pci device */
    device->values.fst = ioread16(device->bar[0]+OFFSET_FST);
    device->values.snd = ioread16(device->bar[0]+OFFSET_SND);
    ...
    device->values.lst = ioread16(device->bar[0]+OFFSET_LST);

    retval = copy_to_user(buffer, &device->values.fst, count);
    return retval;
}
```

And it didn't work :/ I changed the copy_to_user line into

```
retval = copy_to_user(buffer, "dummy", strlen("dummy")+1);
```

but cat /dev/pcidevice still returned nothing.

Next I shifted all ioread16 calls into cdev_open() and I got what I wanted. But now I'm curious why it's only working this way. And how can I make it work the other way?
ATM I think about timers that start copying etc. but some kind of wait until ioreads have finished would be enough.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`copy_to_user()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-copy-to-user.html) function returns number of bytes that could not be copied. On success, it returns `0`. Now imagine how surprised the user space would be when it reads 0 bytes.

The real question is how that actually works inside `cdev_open()`? I hope that you read I/O bar in that function and not sending anything to the user space. In that case, try adding `rmb();` after your reads before calling `copy_to_user()` to make sure every read is finished (`rmb()` is a read memory barrier).

Also, check out LDD [chapter 3](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch03.html) and [chapter 5](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch05.html) if you haven't done so already.

Hope it helps. Happy hacking!